# How to show all texts in single line instead of new lines?

Tags: react-native

From below mentioned code, getting the result as shown in 2nd row in the image:
[image]

How to show all the text elements in the single line as shown in the first row in the image.

```
<Thumbnail square  source={{ uri: some uri }} />
<Text>Butter</Text>
<TextInput
   placeholder="-"
   keyboardType='number-pad'
/>
<Text>Kg</Text>
```

Comment: Can you please describe your question correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please take some time to go through [ask] and [mre].

Comment: please explain your question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<Thumbnail square  source={{ uri: some uri }} />
   <View style={{flexDirection:'row}} > 
      <Text>Butter</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="-"
        keyboardType='number-pad'
        />
    <Text>Kg</Text>
  </View>
```